# Problem with using SVG files as ReactComponent in Gatsby project

Tags: reactjs, svg, gatsby

I'm trying to include svg file in my Gatsby.js project.

LogoIcon component is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as LogoInstagram } from '../assets/img/instagram-logo.svg';

const LogoIcon = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {}
      <LogoInstagram />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LogoIcon;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a 
class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export 
your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named 
imports.

Check the render method of `LogoIcon`.
▶ 20 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
/website/.cache/app.js:67
  64 | const preferDefault = m => (m && m.default) || m
  65 | let Root = preferDefault(require(`./root`))
  66 | domReady(() => {
> 67 |   renderer(<Root />, rootElement, () => {
  68 |     apiRunner(`onInitialClientRender`)
  69 |   })
  70 | })
```

is it related to the SVG file or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few steps in order to get it to work:

1. Install [gatsby-plugin-react-svg](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/)
2. Include it in your `gatsby-config.js` file:

```rb
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
   ...
   `gatsby-plugin-react-svg`,
   ...
  ]
}
```

3. If you already did that, just import it without **curly brackets**:

```js
// import name doesn't matter
import LogoInstagram from '../assets/img/instagram-logo.svg';
```

4. Use it as a usual component:

```
<div>
   <LogoInstagram />
</div>
```

Comment: Changing { ReactComponent as LogoInstagram } to LogoInstagram worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What type should we use?

Comment: I notice that if you try to define the type on a global.d.ts
// fix typescript error of not being able to import svgs has react components
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React = require('react');
  export const ReactComponent:React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & {
    title?: string | undefined;
}> 
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

You get an error: 
Type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

Comment: Solution: 
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}

Comment: @RoyerAdames I don't know actually but try to create a custom type [definition](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/#using-with-typescript)

Comment: @RoyerAdames lol I just about posted the same solution :)

Comment: @RoyerAdames Your solution is not working anymore in new versions. Opened issue about it in official github repo: https://github.com/jacobmischka/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/issues/48